# HapiJS - placing controllers in routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Hapi is something new for me and actually I'm trying to create a good structure for my project.

I've this file: routes/catalogs.js

```
"use strict";
const Boom = require('boom');
const uuid = require('node-uuid');
const Joi = require('joi');
exports.register = function(server, options, next) {
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/catalogs',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
        var catalogs = server.app.mongodb.collection('catalogs');
        catalogs.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
             reply(docs);
        });
    }
});
return next();
};
exports.register.attributes = {
name: 'routes-notifications'
}
```

But instead left all the code on the same file for routing ,I'd like to place the code that's do all the database task in a controller, something similar to this: https://github.com/agendor/sample-hapi-rest-api/blob/master/src/controllers/task.js

but I really can't understand how to do it maybe because on the example, the libs for database is very different and it's mess me. can someone help me to convert my controle to be used with config : {handler: ?

ty !

Comment: Late comment, but I hope it will help others looking for solution. Here is an article that gives examples on implementing controller in Hapi : https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-hapijs/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this [file](https://github.com/simon-p-r/hapi-json-schema/blob/master/lib/handlers/records.js) it shows how you can break mongodb handlers which are added to hapi routes [here](https://github.com/simon-p-r/hapi-json-schema/blob/master/lib/endpoints/records.js).  The aim of this module was to generate data models and methods from json schemas.